# Lucene TwoWayFieldBridge slow query

Tags: java, lucene, full-text-search, hibernate-search

I've built a query in lucene in order to replace an SQL query, but came to the conclusion that the lucene query is a multiple magnitude order slower. With slower I mean, from 250ms to 5000ms, so unacceptable. The setup is a bit special, which I suppose where the problem lies.

The main field that is being indexed and searched upon is of type `Map<String, String>`,and is mapped with:

`@ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class)
 @CollectionTable(name = "data")
 private Map<String, String> data;`

Or in other words, this entity has an associated table with key value pairs. We want to search upon those values, but only on specific keys. So my fieldbridge implementation will make an entry in the document if we encounter a key that meets our needs. (We obviously don't want to store every key in the index.)

The main query is in fact nothing special:

```
FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(getCurrentSession());
try {
    fullTextSession.createIndexer(Form.class).startAndWait();
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    LOG.error("Exception when indexing: ", ex);
}
QueryBuilder builder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Entity.class).get();
org.apache.lucene.search.Query query;
BooleanJunction booleanJunction = builder.bool();

booleanJunction.must(builder.keyword().onFields("data")
.matching(searchString).createQuery());
```

---

My question thus is, what am I doing wrong that this query takes so long to process? If you wish me to provide any extra information that might help you solve this question, please ask and I will provide. I do not know how relevant it is to include the `TwoWayFieldBridge` code, but if the problem may lie there, do ask.

---

**Update:**
The accepted answer is right in that sense that this caused a significant slowdown. I recommend either that your application is indexed from the start, and if this is not possible you can attach a kind of startuplistener (depends on the framework or context used), and use this code to start the indexer. Do note that you need enough available connections open, or this might block your application from ever starting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code you are showing your "search code", then your problem is, that you are indexing the data on each single search. This indexes the `Form` class:

```
try {
    fullTextSession.createIndexer(Form.class).startAndWait();
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    LOG.error("Exception when indexing: ", ex);
}
```

You only want to do this once, or when data changes. You code uses the mass indexer API to index the existing data (`createIndexer(Form.class).startAndWait()`). The purpose of this method is to create an initial index of the existing data. Once the data is indexed you can for example rely on Hibernate Search's automatic indexing which will register a listener for data changes and only index data which gets added or changed. Alternatively you can manually index, if you want/need this level of control. I recommend you refer to the documentation to learn more about these different types of indexing.

Comment: I forgot to update this question, but you are indeed correct. I now handle this at startup, and this caused significant speedup; I found however that the real slowdown came from my ngramfilter on 3 characters, which was pretty slow although the data used was not high. I switched to `WildCardQuery`, which is significantly faster unless many hits are found. I don't really need an answer for that since it is fast enough, but I do wonder what causes this slowdown though. Thanks for your answer